# face recognition - updating the reference face encodings daily

Tags: python, face-recognition, face-detection

how to update the face recognition  reference image encoding daily or weekly to make face detection more accurate. because when time goes there will be changes in peoples face.  so iam thinking to compare face_distance with a threshold value like .40 if it is greater than .40 then iam taking the face encodings. is that right or is there any better way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

- Make two dataset folders
- Name one of them: *face_recognition*
- Second one: *face_recognition_updated*
- Write a function to update dataset with new one

Comment: my question is doing like this in reference with face distance is right or wrong. because face distance is always changing. is there any effective way to get the  similar encodings of a least matching face?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right but you need to be careful about:

- make sure the first/initial enrolled image (or corresponding
  embedding) is of high quality.
- make sure there is no false positive--if some day your software finds
  a false positive (may be a look alike face) then the software will
  enroll the wrong person forever.
- Better option is to re-enroll the person every 5 years.

Comment: this issue is occurring now. when i update the dataset it is capturing the like faces as same. i think i need to increase the threshold